# Learning to use functions in objects... I can't understand why my function is outputting undefined

Tags: javascript, function, object, properties, undefined

So I am creating a simple object with one of the properties being a function... I cannot figure out why when I call it, it outputs undefined!

Here is the code...

```
const team = {
  partner1: "Matthew",
  partner2: "Boab",
  sayTeamNames: (teamObj) => {
    console.log(`${this.partner1} and ${this.partner2}`)
  }
}

team.sayTeamNames();
```

The output I get is...

```
'undefined and undefined'
```

I am fairly sure my syntax is correct. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Arrow functions (`=>`) do not work like old-school functions, and `this` is not bound to the calling object context.

Comment: Also you don't need the parameter if you're not going to pass it.